# how to add pause option for Audio Recorder

Tags: android

In my application I am using ringdroid code and now I want add a functionality like pause/resume option for this. For that I tried like below:

```
 private void recordAudio() {
        mFile = null;
        mTitle = null;
        mArtist = null;
        mRecordingLastUpdateTime = getCurrentTime();
        mRecordingKeepGoing = true;
        mFinishActivity = false;

        final AlertDialog.Builder adBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(RingdroidEditActivity.this);            adBuilder.setTitle(getResources().getText(R.string.progress_dialog_recording);
        adBuilder.setCancelable(true);
      adBuilder.setNegativeButton(
            getResources().getText(R.string.progress_dialog_cancel),
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    mRecordingKeepGoing = false;
                    mFinishActivity = true;
                }
            });
        adBuilder.setPositiveButton(
            getResources().getText(R.string.progress_dialog_stop),
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    mRecordingKeepGoing = false;
                }});
//here is the code i added for pause option
        adBuilder.setNeutralButton("Pause", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                mRecordingKeepGoing = false;
                    adBuilder.show();
            }
        })
        // TODO(nfaralli): try to use a FrameLayout and pass it to the following inflate call.
        // Using null, android:layout_width etc. may not work (hence text is at the top of view).
        // On the other hand, if the text is big enough, this is good enough.          adBuilder.setView(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.record_audio, null));
        mAlertDialog = adBuilder.show();
        Button nbutton = mAlertDialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE);      nbutton.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.lightred));
        Button pbutton = mAlertDialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
 pbutton.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.lightGreen));
        mTimerTextView = (TextView)mAlertDialog.findViewById(R.id.record_audio_timer);
        final SoundFile.ProgressListener listener =
            new SoundFile.ProgressListener() {
                public boolean reportProgress(double elapsedTime) {
                    long now = getCurrentTime();
                    if (now - mRecordingLastUpdateTime > 5) {
                        mRecordingTime = elapsedTime;
                        // Only UI thread can update Views such as TextViews.
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                int min = (int)(mRecordingTime/60);
                                float sec = (float)(mRecordingTime - 60 * min);
                                mTimerTextView.setText(String.format("%d:%05.2f", min, sec));
                            }
                        });
                        mRecordingLastUpdateTime = now;
                    }
                    return mRecordingKeepGoing;
                }
            };

        // Record the audio stream in a background thread
        mRecordAudioThread = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    mSoundFile = SoundFile.record(listener);
                    if (mSoundFile == null) {
                        mAlertDialog.dismiss();
                        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                showFinalAlert(
                                    new Exception(),
                                    getResources().getText(R.string.record_error)
                                );
                            }
                        };
                        mHandler.post(runnable);
                        return;
                    }
                    mPlayer = new SamplePlayer(mSoundFile);
                } catch (final Exception e) {
                    mAlertDialog.dismiss();
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    mInfoContent = e.toString();
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            mInfo.setText(mInfoContent);
                        }
                    });

                    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            showFinalAlert(e, getResources().getText(R.string.record_error));
                        }
                    };
                    mHandler.post(runnable);
                    return;
                }
                mAlertDialog.dismiss();
                if (mFinishActivity){
                    RingdroidEditActivity.this.finish();
                } else {
                    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            finishOpeningSoundFile();
                        }
                    };
                    mHandler.post(runnable);
                }
            }
        };
        mRecordAudioThread.start();
    }
```

But the above is giving the following run time exception.

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
>                         at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:4417)
>                         at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4258)
>                         at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4230)
>                         at com.android.internal.app.AlertController.setupCustomContent(AlertController.java:601)
>                         at com.android.internal.app.AlertController.setupView(AlertController.java:495)
>                         at com.android.internal.app.AlertController.installContent(AlertController.java:253)
>                         at android.app.AlertDialog.onCreate(AlertDialog.java:423)
>                         at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:395)
>                         at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:294)
>                         at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:1112)
>                         at com.ringdroid.RingdroidEditActivity$8.onClick(RingdroidEditActivity.java:739)
>                         at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:166)
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)

can any one help me to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

to record audio, the manifest file of application must have the android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
```

**Attempting to record audio on a device without a microphone will cause the Android system to throw an exception. It is vital, therefore, that the code check for the presence of a microphone before making such an attempt.**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
 import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
 import android.os.Build;
 import android.content.pm.PackageManager;

 public class AudioAppActivity extends Activity {


  protected boolean hasMicrophone() {
    PackageManager pmanager = this.getPackageManager();
    return pmanager.hasSystemFeature(
           PackageManager.FEATURE_MICROPHONE);
  }


   }
```

override the onStart() method of the activity to perform a number of initialization tasks

```
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.app.ActionBar;
 import android.app.Fragment;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.LayoutInflater;
 import android.view.Menu;
 import android.view.MenuItem;
  import android.view.View;
 import android.view.ViewGroup;
 import android.os.Build;
  import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
  import android.media.MediaRecorder;
  import android.os.Environment;
  import android.widget.Button;
  import android.media.MediaPlayer;

  public class AudioAppActivity extends Activity {

   private static MediaRecorder mediaRecorder;
   private static MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

   private static String audioFilePath;
   private static Button pauseButton;
   private static Button playButton;
   private static Button recordButton;

   private boolean isRecording = false;

   @Override
   protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    recordButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.recordButton);
    playButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.playButton);
    pauseButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stopButton);

    if (!hasMicrophone())
    {
        pauseButton.setEnabled(false);
        playButton.setEnabled(false);
        recordButton.setEnabled(false);
    } else {
        playButton.setEnabled(false);
        pauseButton.setEnabled(false);
    }

    audioFilePath = 
        Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() 
             + "/myaudio.3gp";

   }


  }


  public void recordAudio (View view) throws IOException
  {
   isRecording = true;
   pauseButton.setEnabled(true);
   playButton.setEnabled(false);
   recordButton.setEnabled(false);

   try {
   mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(audioFilePath);
     mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
    mediaRecorder.prepare();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
     }

   mediaRecorder.start();           
    }
```

Implement the pauseClicked() Method
  The pauseClicked() method is responsible for enabling the Play button, disabling the Pause button and then stopping and resetting the MediaRecorder instance. The code to achieve this reads as outlined in the following listing and should be added to the AudioAppAcitivy.java file:

```
 public void pauseClicked (View view)
  {

  pauseButton.setEnabled(false);
  playButton.setEnabled(true);

  if (isRecording)
   {    
    recordButton.setEnabled(false);
    mediaRecorder.stop();
    mediaRecorder.release();
    mediaRecorder = null;
    isRecording = false;
    } else {
    mediaPlayer.release();
        mediaPlayer = null;
    recordButton.setEnabled(true);
     }
 }
```